# Distribution of $X$ when a certain condition is satisfied

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I enjoyed this questions:
[Distribution of $X$ when $X,Y$ are i.i.d with $P(X=k \mid X+Y=m) = \frac{1}{m+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790109/distribution-of-x-when-x-y-are-i-i-d-with-px-k-mid-xy-m-frac1m1)

So what about the continuous version?  Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed random variables, with mean $\mu>0$, taking values in $[0,\infty)$, with PDF $p(x)$ such that
$$ p(x) p(y-x) = \frac1y \int_0^y p(z) p(y-z) \, dz  \qquad (0 \le x \le y).$$
I can see that $p(x) = \frac1\mu e^{-x/\mu}$ is a solution.  But is that the only solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your relation tells you that $p(x)p(y-x) = p(0)p(y)$ for all $x\in [0,y]$, since the right hand side is independent of $x$ and thus equal to both of these expressions.

Renaming $y-x = a$ and $x=b$, the relation tells us that  $p(a+b) = C p(a)p(b)$, where $C = p(0)^{-1}$.

Letting $q(x) = Cp(x)$ you get that $q(a+b) = q(a)q(b)$. But $q$ ix a measurable function (it is a probability density multiplied by a constant), so that forces $q(x) = e^{rx}$ for some $r \in \Bbb R$. See e.g. [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8099/fb673c3e9e516e06d9db7800d217bc369914.pdf).

By the condition that $p$ was a probability density, this in turn forces $r<0$ and $p(0) = |r|^{-1}$. So yes, it must be an exponentially distributed variable.

Comment: Ok I replaced the hyperlink with a better reference.

Comment: One additional subtlety I forgot to consider is that $p(0)$ could be zero. But then by setting $x=y/2$ in that relation, we would get $p(y/2)^2=0$ for all $y$. Thus $p$ would be identically zero.

Comment: That's a much better solution than I had in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790109/distribution-of-x-when-x-y-are-i-i-d-with-px-k-mid-xy-m-frac1m1/3790302#3790302.  Thank you.